# Get the sum of a multikey dict by one key and add it to a datfarme column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe and a dict as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]]),columns=['a', 'b'])
df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  4  5

dict
{(0, 'A', 1): 1, (0, 'A', 2): 2, (1, 'B', 1): 3, (1, 'B', 2): 4}
```

I am trying to get the total sum by the first key of the dict and add the result as a new column to my dataframe.

This is what I have so far, but I am thinking there must be a more efficient way to do this.

```
total_by_1st={}
for (x, _, _), v in dict.items():
    if x in total_by_1st:
       total_by_1st[x] += v
    else:
       total_by_1st[x]=v

total_by_1st
{0: 3, 1: 7}
df['c'] = df.index.map(total_by_1st)
df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to get the total sum by the first key of the dict and add the result as a new column to my dataframe

You can convert to series and sum on level 0:

```
df['new'] = pd.Series(d).sum(level=0)
```

---

```
print(df)

   a  b  new
0  1  2    3
1  4  5    7
```

Where `d` is the name of the variable which stores your dictionary. Please note that you should not name a variable same as a builtin (*`d` or something similar instead of `dict`*)

Comment: Similarly with itertools: `[sum([d.get(i) for i in v]) for k,v in itertools.groupby(d.keys(),key=lambda x: x[0])]`